# Fail to load PiplineModel/LogisticRegressionModel mlib spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I have a problem with loading a serialized `PiplineModel` that contains a `LogisticRegressionModel` stage. I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "coefficients" does not exist.
```

I had tried both loading the full pipeline and just logistic stage and get the same error. Additionally, I checked whether `coeficients()` returns values prior to saving the model and it does.

Any ideas of what might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue days ago and finally, I found it was caused by incompatible versions of Spark used to save & load model, for example, use Spark 2.1.x to train and save a model, then use Spark 2.0.x to load this model.

For more details, you can refer to this JIRA issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17163.